# Yii2: How to print a gridview?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, export-to-pdf, printing-web-page

I am using [yii2-export](http://demos.krajee.com/export) library to print a table.

The table has 600 rows but the user only wants to print the first 20 rows.

The user exports to a PDF file (so then he can print it) but it's big so the PHP server doesn't respond.

I tried printing with the browser (CTRL+P) but it prints buttons and also it so ugly.

Comment: In chrome (79.0.3945.130) (also in firefox 72.0.2) print view you can see header sort links, button links... would be nice to turn off.

Comment: Yii version 2.0.32

Answer (score 0):

Please check [`batchSize`](http://demos.krajee.com/export#option-batchSize) parameter of Export Menu or add `pagination` and `limit` filter to `dataprovider`.

[Yii2 dataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html)